# kendo toolTip event is not defined

Tags: javascript, events, kendo-ui, tooltip, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a tooltip that will pull in some information, however, I am having some trouble getting it to work. When I try to add a RequestStart event, or any event, I get an error that shows

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart is not defined"
```

I don't know why it is not allowing this code. I have pretty much the exact same code in a few different places. Here is the code that is getting the error.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
                    .For("#ShipSchedule-wrapper")
                    .Filter(".ShipSchedule-jobs-wrapper")
                    .LoadContentFrom("DesignSetTooltip", "ProductionOverview")
                    //.Content("toolTipTestContent")
                    .Position(TooltipPosition.Left)
                    .AutoHide(false)
                    .Width(600)
                    //.Height(300)
                    .ShowOn(TooltipShowOnEvent.Click)
                    .Events(events => events.RequestStart("ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart"))
                    //.Events(events => events.Show("onTap"))
        )
```

Here is the ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart

```
function ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart(e) {
        e.options.data = {
            designSetId: e.target.data("designSetId")
        }
    }
```

So, if anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it.

**Edit**
Could it be that I have the tooltip .For and .Filter set up on ids that are added in in a function?

Comment: Double check everything...I pasted your code into one of my views and it worked fine(although I don't have the LoadContentFrom endpoint).  The only thing I changed from what you provided is that I put the ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart() function inside a script block at the bottom of the .cshtml and added a couple dummy divs for the tooltip .For() and .Filter().  I hit a break point inside the function and everything when I clicked on my .ShipSchedule-jobs-wrapper div.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, I guess I'll keep looking over everything. I would bet it's something simple I am missing, but I cannot seem to get anywhere I have the ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart() function inside a script block at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widget is getting rendered before the function. See [Kendo Fundamentals on Deferred](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#configuration-Deferring).

Change your widget:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
                    .For("#ShipSchedule-wrapper")
                    .Filter(".ShipSchedule-jobs-wrapper")
                    .LoadContentFrom("DesignSetTooltip", "ProductionOverview")
                    .Position(TooltipPosition.Left)
                    .AutoHide(false)
                    .Width(600)
                    .ShowOn(TooltipShowOnEvent.Click)
                    .Events(events => events.RequestStart("ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart"))
                    .Deferred() // Defer script gen to below
        )
```

Then in your script tag at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShipScheduleDsTooltip_RequestStart(e) {
        e.options.data = {
            designSetId: e.target.data("designSetId")
        }
    }

    @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts(false)    // Render the widget js here after the function

</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!